# Configure Windows IIS authentication using Nginx

Tags: nginx, iis, asp.net

I have a web API hosted using the IIS Express and it is running in my localhost using the port number 17770. I also installed Nginx in my localhost which is using the port number 8070.

The goal is to do basic authentication to the API which is hosted using the IIS Express through the Nginx.

Here is my config file. I would like to know how to test weather the configuration is working and authenticating my web API.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    accept_mutex off;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  29;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    client_header_timeout   10;
    send_timeout            10;

    limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;
     server_tokens           off;

    tcp_nopush              on;
    tcp_nodelay             off;

    gzip  on;
     gzip_comp_level         9;
     gzip_http_version       1.0;
     gzip_disable            "MSIE [1-6]\."

     # Enable GZIP compression for the following MIME types (text/html is included by default).
    gzip_types              # Plain Text
                            text/plain
                            text/css
                            text/mathml
                            application/rtf
                            # JSON
                            application/javascript
                            application/json
                            application/manifest+json
                            application/x-web-app-manifest+json
                            text/cache-manifest
                            # XML
                            application/atom+xml
                            application/rss+xml
                            application/xslt+xml
                            application/xml
                            # Fonts
                            font/opentype
                            font/otf
                            font/truetype
                            application/font-woff
                            application/vnd.ms-fontobject
                            application/x-font-ttf
                            # Images
                            image/svg+xml
                            image/x-icon;
    # Enables inserting the 'Vary: Accept-Encoding' response header.
    gzip_vary               on;


    server {
        listen       8070;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:17770;

            # The default minimum configuration required for ASP.NET Core
            # See https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html?highlight=nginx#configure-a-reverse-proxy-server
            proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
            # Turn off changing the URL's in headers like the 'Location' HTTP header.
            proxy_redirect          off;
            # Forwards the Host HTTP header.
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            # The Kestrel web server we are forwarding requests to only speaks HTTP 1.1.
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            # Adds the 'Connection: keep-alive' HTTP header.
            proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;

            # Sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body.
            client_max_body_size    10m;
            # Sets buffer size for reading client request body.
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            # Defines a timeout for establishing a connection with a proxied server.
            proxy_connect_timeout   90;
            # Sets a timeout for transmitting a request to the proxied server.
            proxy_send_timeout      90;
            # Defines a timeout for reading a response from the proxied server.
            proxy_read_timeout      90;
            # Sets the number and size of the buffers used for reading a response from the proxied server.
            proxy_buffers           32 4k;
        }

        #location / {
        #    root   html;
        #    index  index.html index.htm;
        #}

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }



        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved after adding the below

```
server {
        listen       8070;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /swagger {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:17770/swagger;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
```